# Python: The output generated from a function which contains print to a string variable

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose you have this function:

```
def a():
    student_havnt_done={'Uploaded the data',
     'You did extra work for this question and you deserve a round of applause.',
     'You selected both stocks from different industries'}

    for number, letter in enumerate(student_havnt_done):
        print(number+1, letter)  
    pass
```

You want to store the output it has into a string variable call it ca as

```
ca=str(a())
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. Is there a way to get this work?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function so the value of `a()` will be `None`. Use the `return` keyword to return something when the function is called then you can store that into a variable.

Comment: @techytushar I want to return the printed statements in a for loop executed in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment above, this should work:

```py
def a():
    student_havnt_done={'Uploaded the data',
     'You did extra work for this question and you deserve a round of applause.',
     'You selected both stocks from different industries'}
    s = ''
    for number, letter in enumerate(student_havnt_done):
        s += f'{number+1} {letter}\n' 
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is as follow

```
v=['\n'+str(number+1)+' '+letter for number, letter in enumerate(student_havnt_done)]
a='\t'.join(v)
print(a)
```

where a will be the string variable I want it to have, but I am not sure if there was an easier way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not storing it, rather returning it to the called function.
What you have to do just pass a list to that function and append the values to it and finally returning it. Later convert the list to string to get your desired result.
You can try the below code, it works fine as well.

```
def a(ca):
    student_havnt_done={'Uploaded the data',
     'You did extra work for this question and you deserve a round of applause.',
     'You selected both stocks from different industries'}

    for number, letter in enumerate(student_havnt_done):
        temp = str(number+1)+' '+ str(letter )
        ca.append(temp)  
    pass
    return(ca)
```

Now calling it, and converting list to string

```
ca = []
a(ca)
final string = ' '.join(ca)
```

below output :-

> '1 You selected both stocks from different industries 2 Uploaded the
>   data 3 You did extra work for this question and you deserve a round of
>   applause.'